# Что то упущенное в коде Java

Tags: java

Есть такая задача, которая не клеется, буду признателен за помощь:

Для проверки остаточных знаний учеников после летних каникул, учитель младших классов решил начинать каждый урок с того, чтобы задавать каждому ученику пример из таблицы умножения, но в классе 15 человек, а примеры среди них не должны повторяться. В помощь учителю напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран 15 случайных примеров из таблицы умножения (от 22 до 99, потому что задания по умножению на 1 и на 10 — слишком просты). При этом среди 15 примеров не должно быть повторяющихся (примеры 23 и 32 и им подобные пары считать повторяющимися).

Вот мой код, но что то не выходит:

```
public class MassiveClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //создаем два массива
        int[][] mas1=new int[3][5];
        int[][] mas2=new int[3][5];
        //заполняем их случайными числами
        for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<mas1[i].length;j++){
                mas1[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*8+2);
                mas2[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*8+2);
            }
        }
        //выводим их на экран
        for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<mas1[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(mas1[i][j]+"*"+mas2[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        //создаем внутренний счетчик для проверки на совпадения элементов,
        //в случае нахождения, переопределяем их новыми случайными числами
        for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
            label:for(int j=0;j<mas1[i].length;j++){
                int po1=mas1[i][j], po2=mas2[i][j],in1=i,in2=j;
                for(int k=0;k<mas1.length;k++){
                    for(int r=0;r<mas1[k].length;r++){
                        //если элемент не сравнивает сам себя
                        if(k!=in1&&r!=in2){
                            //проверка на совпадаемость
                            if((mas1[k][r]==po1&&mas2[k][r]==po2)||
                               (mas1[k][r]==po2&&mas2[k][r]==po1)){
                                //в случае совпадений - переназначение,
                                //обнуление счетчиков, и начало проверки с 
                                //самого начала
                                mas1[k][r]=(int)(Math.random()*8+2);
                                mas2[k][r]=(int)(Math.random()*8+2);
                                k=0;r=0;i=0;j=0;
                                break label;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }             
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //Вывод массива без совпадений 
        for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<mas1[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(mas1[i][j]+"*"+mas2[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Как по мне то я или не правильно задал условие проверки на совпадаемость, или тоже как мне кажется не правильно обнуляет счетчики.

Comment: помогите, я в отчаянии, уже неделю решить не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не джавист, но у вас какой-то ад написан. Зачем два массива? Почему именно двумерные массивы 3*5? Какие обнуления счетчиков? В псевдокоде все будет так:

```
equations = int[15][2]
i = 0
while(i < 15) {
    int[2] equation = createRandomEquation()
    if (notInArray(equation, equations) {
        equations[i] = equation
        i++
    }
}
int[2] function createRandomEquation() {
    int[2] equation
    do {
        equation = { random(2, 10), random(2, 10) }
    }
    while (equation[0] * equation[1] < 22 || equation[0] * equation[1] > 99)
    return equation
}
bool notInArray(needle, haystack) {
    foreach (haystack as pair) {
        if ((pair[0] == needle[0] && pair[1] == needle[1]) ||
                (pair[0] == needle[1] && pair[1] == needle[0]))
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Да уж, с высказыванием по поводу жуткого кода ТС согласен.

Answer (score 0):

ваша задача решается следующим образом:

1) создаем контейнер который хранит состояние использования каждого теста
2) генерируем 2 числа которые соответсвуют заданным условиям теста
3) проверяем пара включена в тест или нет

код:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyTableTest {

    private static final Random numberRandom = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // store usage of each numbers pair
        boolean[] usage = new boolean[9 * 9];

        // generate tests (pairs of numbers to multiply)
        int[][] r1 = getTestPairs(usage, 15);
        int[][] r2 = getTestPairs(usage, 3);
        int[][] r3 = getTestPairs(usage, 4);

        displayTest(r1, "new test for 15 studends");
        displayTest(r2, "test for 3 more studends using the same usage table");
        displayTest(r3, "test for 3 more studends using the same usage table");
    }

    /**
     * Draw test results
     * 
     * @param tests
     * @param message
     */
    private static void displayTest(int[][] tests, String message) {
        System.out.println("Test: " + message);
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            int[] test = tests[i];
            // System.out.println("Test entry: " + test[0] + " x " + test[1] + " = ? (" + test[0] * test[1] + ") ");
            System.out.println("Test entry: " + test[0] + " x " + test[1] + " = ?");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Generate test pairs for specified amount of tests
     * 
     * @param usage - stores usage of the tests
     * @param amount - specifies amount of tests to generate
     * @return
     */
    private static int[][] getTestPairs(boolean[] usage, int amount) {
        int[][] result = new int[amount][2];

        // iterating over each test to generate
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length;) {
            // select test to generate
            int[] test = result[i];

            // generate two random numbers
            test[0] = random();
            test[1] = random();

            // multiply numbers (to get index of element inside usage array)
            int tmp = test[0] * test[1];

            // decrease by one cause we are using index not the value itself
            tmp = tmp - 1;

            // check if this test was already used
            if (!usage[tmp]) {
                // test was NOT used, so:
                // we mark it as used and move to next test entry
                usage[tmp] = true;
                i++;
            } else {
                // test was used, so:
                // going to next loop iteration
                // actions will be repeated for the same test entry
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get appropriate random number: 2 <= result < 10 (the same as 2 <= result <= 9)
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static int random() {
        return numberRandom.nextInt(8) + 2;
    }

}
```

пример вывода в консоль:

```
Test: new test for 15 studends
Test entry: 9 x 8 = ?
Test entry: 4 x 9 = ?
Test entry: 6 x 2 = ?
Test entry: 5 x 3 = ?
Test entry: 6 x 5 = ?
Test entry: 3 x 6 = ?
Test entry: 3 x 2 = ?
Test entry: 5 x 8 = ?
Test entry: 7 x 5 = ?
Test entry: 2 x 2 = ?
Test entry: 8 x 3 = ?
Test entry: 3 x 3 = ?
Test entry: 9 x 6 = ?
Test entry: 2 x 4 = ?
Test entry: 4 x 4 = ?

Test: test for 3 more studends using the same usage table
Test entry: 7 x 8 = ?
Test entry: 9 x 9 = ?
Test entry: 6 x 8 = ?

Test: test for 3 more studends using the same usage table
Test entry: 5 x 4 = ?
Test entry: 7 x 6 = ?
Test entry: 7 x 3 = ?
Test entry: 7 x 7 = ?
```